# Refer to a Freelance option in upwork could improve my score?

Tags: freelance-websites, client-support, marketing

**I am relatively new** at [upwork.com](http://upwork.com) and since my first invitation to interview and work done, I have to received more invitations to interviews, So **I have to ignore some** but I think that if I ignore the invitations will impact my score so I had to research about **What happen if I ignore an invitation?** and I found this [post] at upwork.(https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/Declining-interviews/td-p/141772):

> But if you just click a button indicating the reason for your decline,
> then nothing bad can happen.
>
> You will actually gain credit toward your Responsiveness score if you
> make sure you always reply to invitation requests promptly... within
> 24 hours. Your score benefits whether you decline or accept.

I have a curious about the **"Refer to a Freelance"** Option. How can I refer if this work don't let me know other freelance. anyone use this option? anyone know how to know another freelance colleagues? for share experience and opinion of how to deal with difficult clients especially with projects related to specific areas like Engineering or Data Science?

**Refer to a freelance could improve my Score?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used it, and you can search the freelancer with particular skills and read their profile. You can also refer your friend who is also a freelancer.